# Convert ipython notebooks to pdf on windows 8.1

Tags: python, windows, pdf

Is there anyway where i can convert **ipython** notebooks to pdf on windows 8.1?

I found solutions, but only for Linux and macOS not for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You could install Latex for Windows (http://latex-project.org/ftp.html) and then do the conversion to Latex with a post to PDF that is mentioned in iPython's [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html). I believe the command is something like this:

```
ipython nbconvert --to latex --post PDF notebook.ipynb
```

Or you could convert to rst and then use the [rst2pdf](http://rst2pdf.ralsina.me/) tool to convert that to PDF.

```
ipython nbconvert --to rst notebook.ipynb
```

Then once you have converted to rst, you can use rst2pdf like this:

```
rst2pdf.py notebook.rst -o notebook.pdf
```

Comment: where I must type the following command? rst2pdf.py notebook.rst -o notebook.pdf  I am use Windows 8.1

Comment: If you've added **c:\Python27\Scripts** (or whatever Python you have) to your path, then you should be able to just open up your terminal and run it as is. Otherwise, go to the location of your rst file and type c:\python27\scripts\rst2pdf